# Bash command line args Tab-auto-completion via a data service

Tags: cloud-service, search-engine, bash, autocomplete, shell-extension

Think of an action to one of the several thousands of services.

I want to narrow down service selection via Tab-completion by specifying one by one:

- prod, test, dev
- country (AU, US, ...)
- function (frontend, backend, ...)
- cluster name (service is a part of)
- any other properties
- ...
- service name (reduced set based on input above)

The more args get specified,
the more specific value set is proposed for the next arg.

**Is there anything existing integrated with Bash?**

---

**DETAILS**

It could be anything else solving the problem above,
but I see a setup involving:

- A client = some (intermediate) command name to bind Bash completion to.
- A (local | remote) standby service with loaded/indexed data for quick completion replies.
- A user sends all `Tab`-auto-completion requests via client to the server.
- Once all arg values got `Tab`-completed by the user,
  `Enter` relays the data from the server to the client to execute an action:

  - log in to the destination
  - look up remote resource state
  - etc.

A (web) UI does not cut it - ultimately, the target is a shell env anyway.

There could be some tools specific to some cloud providers,
but I'm looking for an agnostic one providing:

- all the client-server interfaces,
- plugin support for various data sources,
- configure-able (domain-specific) lookup,

I came up with a POC, but it will take time to mature -
still hoping to find anything existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [argrelay](https://github.com/uvsmtid/argrelay) when facing a similar problem.

---

Given there were no comments/answers and search gave no acceptable results for many weeks, the POC has matured enough and the outcome is quite satisfying.